# How would you express mutual exclusion of facts in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Suppose you are working with a genealogy database. Some records are missing. You might know that people named "John" were male, and people named "Mary" were female, etc.

```
male(X)   :- first_name(X, "John").
female(X) :- first_name(X, "Mary").
```

For people with exotic or foreign names, their gender can be unclear, but it must have been one of the two. Marriage (before this century) was between opposite genders.

```
female(X) :- wed(X, Y), male  (Y).
male  (X) :- wed(X, Y), female(Y).
```

Knowing that someone's gender was either male or female (even if you don't know which) is an important tidbit in deciphering identities and relationships.

How would you encode this knowledge in Prolog?

---

```
female(X) :- person(X), not(male(X)).
```

is incorrect, as it makes you conclude that everyone is female unless they can be proven to be male.

Comment: I'm too coffee-deficient to think deeply about this but you need to abandon the logic-for-programming-and-occasional-modeling of Prolog and go meta, using Prolog as the programming language and implement another logic for different modeling on top. This should be of interest: [Logic programming with strong negation and inexact predicates](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.975.3445&rank=1) (Gerd Wagner, 1991). It is part of the thin but powerful book [Vivid Logic](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-57604-5), which has a one-page metainterpreter at the back.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer yes, reading a book every time one feels like they should write a question on SO is indeed a great idea. "O brave new world, that has such people in't". I should also do 10 push ups every time I feel like writing an answer on SO (and maybe 5 for a comment); I will be jacked.

Comment: Any question that starts with "suppose that" and code fragments is strictly worse than a question with a minimal yet complete and reproducible code example.

Comment: @TA_intern Reading abook is better than wallowing in ignorance. MaxB seems to target the theoretical aspects quite a lot, so this recommendation is not out of place. No need to get huffy about it. And really, how would you answer the question that boils down to "I want to have strong negation".

Comment: @DavidTonhofer You seem to have misread the tone of my comment. I fully agree that reading a book is better than asking on SO. This is what my comment says, too, even after re-reading it carefully. Same goes for the push ups, definitely better to do exercise than spend time chatting with a stranger on the internet. A push up is always better than no push up, while a comment is so often misunderstood that I would go as far as saying that no comment is always better than any comment.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer There is a good reason why SO guidelines discourage the kind of questions that OP has been asking a lot lately.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thanks for the links. I'll check them out.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer How does Vivid Logic compare to [WFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_semantics)? I'm not too familiar with either, but Flora2 and SWI implement WFS, apparently.

Comment: @MaxB I do not know yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a ton of assumptions about many things. The question is more complicated than it needs to be because of this.

In your case, "is not known to be male" is not enough for "is female", you say. But you also say, "is not known to be male AND is married to a male" is enough.

In some hypothetical program (which we don't have in your question, so it isn't really reproducible) you would maybe write:

```
is_female(X) :- female(X).
is_female(X) :- \+ is_male(X), married_to(X, Y), is_male(Y).
```

There is stuff that came from filling in the blanks in your question. Is there need for `female/1` *and* for `is_female/1`? It depends. Etc

Comment: *"But you also say, "is not known to be male AND is married to a male" is enough."*  -- Where do you get that? The first premise seems unnecessary, as does `\+ is_male(X)`.

Comment: @MaxB I have no idea what you are trying to achieve then. I guess I shouldn't answer questions that are too sophisticated for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

> incorrect, as it makes you conclude that everyone is female unless they can be proven to be male

This kind of reasoning, slightly refined, is *not* incorrect. Everyone *is* potentially female unless they are proven to be male. What else would they be?

```
possibly_female(Person) :-
    person(Person),
    \+ proven_male(Person).
possibly_female(Person) :-
    proven_female(Person).

possibly_male(Person) :-
    person(Person),
    \+ proven_female(Person).
possibly_male(Person) :-
    proven_male(Person).
```

Although, depending on what you want to do, rather than using a division into known/possible genders it might be simpler to use a three-way male/female/unknown division:

```
unknown_gender(Person) :-
    person(Person),
    \+ proven_female(Person),
    \+ proven_male(Person).
```

(Lots of caveats about gender binarism apply to the real world, though arguably if you're really modeling historical databases based on a binary assumption, it's reasonable to use that model.)

Comment: The issue of the question is that is conflates several things (exclusivity, genders, genealogy) and at the end it is not at all clear what the question is about. Good attempt at an answer nevertheless.

Comment: @TA_intern From the dictionary, one of the meanings of "exclusive" is *" **excluding** or having power to exclude"*  so here it refers to `male(X)` and `female(X)` **excluding** each other. I hope this clears up the misunderstanding.